# relative path to images in external js script

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla2.5, relative-path

I'm writing a component in Joomla and want to use JavaScript.

I got the JavaScript part working in a separat test html page, but now I want to include it in the Joomla component.

The problem is the relative file paths for the images. The images are stored in the media folder of joomla:

media/com_component/images

I include the external js-file with this command:

$document->addScript(JURI::Root().'components/com_component/script.js');

In the script I need the path to the image folder. I don't want to hard code the absolute path in the script. 
How can I get the relative paths? Do/can I use Joomla functions for that?

Thank you

Comment: If you can, use the HTML `<base>` tag.

Comment: Have you tried `../` ?

Comment: I will try, when I get home. But for ../ I must know how often to go back, I was looking for something similar to JURI::Root(). I guess that's not relative then?!

Comment: People just use JURI::root() as you have mentioned and then hardcoded path. I would comment that maybe you should be adding images via PHP first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to put the file path information in the css file (set the image as the background of the link). 
This way the js-script is independent of the image's file path.